# Extending Wordpress Security to unrelated directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, subdirectory

I've had a fair go at googling this and cannot find a definitive answer for it, hopefully will be able to get somewhere on here.

I'm looking to user a subdirectory of my wordpress site as part of a members area within the site itself, is there a way to edit either the HT Access file or something within the wordpress code to extend the security to hide the pages to people who are not logged in to the site?

Comment: do you mean ALL pages, specific pages, posts ? archives ? This is fairly basic wordpress functionality ( to some extent - for example password protect individual posts and pages  ) and if not enough - there are a lot of plugins .

Comment: No, I perhaps didn't explain as well as I could have. I'm looking to extend the security to pages outwith wordpress. So a directory not actually included in the wordpress set up or site files can be protected by the same user database as the wordpress pages themselves are.